# Ask for login when user tries direct link to advertisement#show action with Devise and Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, popup

I have two different models that can authenticate: *user* and *advertisement*

I have set up this in advertisement controller:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:show,:edit,:update]
```

I wanted to have pop up login form each time visititor tries to access restricted area. In this case `advertisement#show`

If visitor tries to access show action from index page everything works perfect.

For that I have set up like this:

In **application helper**:

```
def link_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)
    
  html_options, options, name = options, name, block if block_given?
  options ||= {}
  html_options = convert_options_to_data_attributes(options, html_options)
  url = url_for(options)
  html_options['href'] ||= url if url.present?
  
  if html_options["require_login"] and not user_signed_in?
    html_options.delete "data-toggle"
    html_options.delete "data-remote"
    html_options.delete "data-target"
    html_options.delete "data-method"
    html_options['href'] = '#'
    html_options['onclick'] = "loginModalShow();"
    html_options['class'] = "" if html_options['class'].nil?
    html_options['class'] = html_options['class']
  end

  if html_options["require_login2"] and not advertisement_signed_in?
    html_options.delete "data-toggle"
    html_options.delete "data-remote"
    html_options.delete "data-target"
    html_options.delete "data-method"
    html_options['href'] = '#'
    html_options['onclick'] = "advertisementModalShow();"
    html_options['class'] = "" if html_options['class'].nil?
    html_options['class'] = html_options['class']
  end
  content_tag(:a, name || url, html_options, &block)
end
```

**Application layout:**

```
<%= render partial: "shared/login" %>
```

In **_login** partial:

```
<% unless user_signed_in? %>
<script>
    function loginModalShow() { 
        $('#loginmodal').modal('show') (e)
         e.preventDefault();
    }
</script>
 <%end%>

<% unless advertisement_signed_in? %>
<script>
    function advertisementModalShow() { 
        $('#advertisementmodal').modal('show') (e)
         e.preventDefault();
    }
</script>

 <%end%>
```

And I have those modals in application layout.

**Problem**: When visitor tries to use direct link, he is redirected to login page. I can't figure it out, how to show login popup each time visitor tries to use direct link.

example: `http://localhost:3000/ru/advertisements/46`

Any help would be great!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the before_action it is run during the request before your controllers show action is executed thus redirecting to the login page. The reason your link_to works is because you are changing the links behavior and it isn't hitting the before_action because you specify the `only` filter. You can remove the before action and in your view check if there is a `current_user` and if not display the modal manually else proceed as usual.